# Why can't I parse this double_?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

When I parse an input as a std::string, I get the string, but when I parse this as a double_, the fusion struct contains some very small number rather than what is expected.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

#include <string>

// http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/employee.cpp

namespace FormatConverter {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    // TODO: should this have an initializer?
    struct asc {
        double timestamp;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    FormatConverter::asc,
      (double, timestamp)
)

namespace FormatConverter {

    template <typename Iterator>
    struct asc_parser : qi::grammar< Iterator, asc(), ascii::space_type >
    {
        asc_parser()
            : asc_parser::base_type(start) {
                timestamp %= qi::double_ ;
                start %= timestamp ;
                ;
        }
        qi::rule< Iterator, double, ascii::space_type > timestamp;
        qi::rule< Iterator, asc(), ascii::space_type > start;
    };
}
```

And I am testing this with:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE parser
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

#include "../FormatConverter/FormatConverter.h"

#include <string>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( TestSuite1 )
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( timestamp ) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    using iterator_type = std::string::iterator;
    using parser_type = FormatConverter::asc_parser<iterator_type>;

    parser_type grammar;
    FormatConverter::asc record;

    std::string str("161.096841 ");
    auto beg = str.begin();
    auto end = str.end();

    auto success = qi::phrase_parse(beg, end, grammar, ascii::space, record);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(success);
    BOOST_REQUIRE(beg==end);

    std::cout << "timestamp: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(record) << std::endl;
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Comment: everytime, i swear i can't write it properly. i know it, but that's always the way I type it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed a `()` in the attribute:

```
qi::rule< Iterator, double, ascii::space_type > timestamp;
```

should be

```
qi::rule< Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type > timestamp;
```

Because the params order in `qi::rule` can be arbitrary (except Iterator), internally the lib uses some traits to recognize which is attr, which is skipper, ...etc. The attr field has to be in the form of function-sig, i.e. `synthesized(inherited)`, if you write `double`, it won't be recognized as an attr, so your `timestamp` rule will actually have `unused_type` instead of `double` as its attr, that means, `record.timestamp` won't be filled by the parser, it's uninitialized.

Comment: The author decided to support the plain form `T` in addition to `T()` recently[[1](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/e34a955f2fbbf374870dee3329f89805cd775e6c)], so the former will work in future releases.

Comment: Thanks. I had made the assumption that the () wouldn't be required for builtin types. To me, it does seem counterintuitive to write double()